# Continuity of $\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I saw this question on an interim exam; Let $f: \mathbb{R^2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be given by

$f(x,y)= \left\{ 
\begin{array}{}
             \sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}  &x^2+y^2 \leq 1, \ y \geq 0 \\
              0 &\text{Otherwise}
\end{array}
\right.$

Now, the question was: Is $f$ continuous in $(0,0)$, $(1,0)$, $(1,1)$. Using the fact that $f$ is continuous in $a=(a_1,a_2)$ iff $\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (a_1,a_2)}f(x,y) = f(a_1,a_2)$, I thought that $f$ is continuous in $(0,0)$ and $(1,0)$, although I am not sure about $(1,1)$.

Could someone verify that my assumption about the first two points is correct, and help me verifying the last point? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hint: $f(0,0)=1$, but $f\left(0,-\frac1n\right)=0$ for each natural $n$.

Comment: f (0,0) is what?  f (0,-e);1>e>0 is what?  Is that continuous?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Let $(x_n) $ and $(y_n) $ such that

$x_n\to 1$ and $y_n\to 1$.

then for $n $ great enough,

$x_n>\frac{\sqrt {2}}{2}$ and $y_n>\frac {\sqrt {2}}{2}$.
thus $x_n^2+y_n^2>1$ and
$$f (x_n,y_n)=0=\lim_{n\to+\infty}f (x_n,y_n)=f (1,1) $$

$f $ is continuous at $(1,1) $.

> for $(0,0) $.

$$\lim_{+\infty}f (0,1/n)=1$$
$$ \lim_{+\infty}f (0,-1/n)=0$$
$f $ not continuous at $(0,0) $.

Comment: Great! Can you also do this for $(1,0)$ and $(0,0)$. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @MartindeQuincey Yes.

Comment: @MartindeQuincey Why dowvoting.

Comment: Was not me, someone else

Comment: @MartindeQuincey The downvoter did well. i edited.